# PHP new keyword with directory?

Tags: php, doctrine

I am looking at this tutorial:

http://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/05/setting-up-codeigniter-2-with-doctrine-2-the-right-way/

and I see the new keyword used like so:

```
$doctrineClassLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine', APPPATH.'libraries');
```

I am not used to seeing the new keyword used with what appears to be a directory or something?  I was looking through the PHP manual to find similar usage and what this means (and how it works) but didn't see what I was looking for.

Can someone explain this usage to me or point me to example code in the PHP manual.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: namespaces http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: What Pekka and galchen are saying is that that's not a "directory", it's a "namespace" in PHP. Yeah, I don't like it either, but it is what it is.

Comment: The appearance is misleading but not quite wrong. While namespaces were intended to prevent identifier clashes, they are commonly used just for grouping and mimicking the directory structure of used class scripts.

Answer (score 3):

PHP 5.3 introduced namespaces. Namespace are another way of structuring your program and the library you are working with is using them extensively. You can basically put classes and functions inside a namespace. Namespaces can be nested. In order to use them you prefix every namespace by a backslash.

You can read more about namespaces in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).